# How to add angular2-logger into systemjs.config.js for Angular2?

Tags: angular, logging

I am trying to add logging into the Quick-start application

I follow https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-logger but it has slightly different syntax as compared to the the latest Quickstart.

I added into map

```
angular2-logger': 'node_modules/angular2-logger'
```

Then I modified packages adding angular2-logger:

```
angular2-logger: { 
    defaultExtension: 'js' 
}
```

So the packages becane as follows:

```
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  angular2-logger:  { 
      defaultExtension: 'js' 
  },
   rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
 }
```

As a result “Hello Angular” stopped appearing on the screen while running "npm start"

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
'angular2-log': {
         defaultExtension: 'js'
     },
```

Use single quotes around angular2-log